# Two dimensional array with different lengths (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there an opportunity to create two dimensional Arrays with different lengths in the second dimension? For example like this:

[true] [true] [true]

[true]

[true] [true] [true] [true] [true]

Preferably without creating another class (like buckets) and without knowing the actual length of the array.

Comment: So you haven't tried `boolean[][] blub = new boolean[10][];`, because ...?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, arrays in a 2D array don't have the have same size. E.g.:

```
boolean[][] twoDimensionalArray = new boolean[3][];
twoDimensionalArray[0] = new boolean[]{true, true, true};
twoDimensionalArray[1] = new boolean[]{true};
twoDimensionalArray[2] = new boolean[]{true, true, true, true, true};
```

Answer (score 2):

Java does not have 2-dimensional arrays.

Java has 1-dimensional arrays whose elements can be any primitive or reference type - including other arrays.